# Error: File to import not found or unreadable. Only with scss files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass, rake, asset-pipeline

I'm having errors to import files with extension scss even if the file is empty. But if i change the extension of that empty file to css, IT WORKS!!!

Everything started to happen when i change the rails version from 3.2.3 to 3.2.15 because dropdown from bootstrap wasn't working.

I have no problem running my **rails s** command. But when i try to push to Heroku it throws error:

**File to import not found or unreadable: custom.scss.**

This is my **application.css** file:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
*/
@import "custom.scss"; //or any file with extension .scss it throws error
```

if i run

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

it throws the same error

```
File to import not found or unreadable: custom.scss.
Load paths:
  c:/Users/jgutierrezco/RubyWorkspace/sample_app_test
  c:/Users/jgutierrezco/RubyWorkspace/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  (in c:/Users/jgutierrezco/RubyWorkspace/sample_app_test/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
(sass):15
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:67:in             `rescue in import'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:45:in `import'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:28:in `imported_file'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:37:in `css_import?'
....
....
```

As i said before, if i change the file custom.scss to custom.css the **bundle exec rake assets:precompile** ends without error.

If i try to import an EMPTY scss file, it won't work only by the fact (i think) that the extension is **scss**.

Is there any configuration that i'm missing? Mainly because i changed rails from version 3.2.3 to 3.2.15

Comment: did you try without extension ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After beeing wandering everywhere someone in the bootstrap-sass github repository pointed me to the right direction.

I had to rename my **application.css** to **application.scss**.

That did the trick!